# Excluding data from firestore search

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a dating app. Right now we don't want to show the data of users that users have already seen.
For example, let's suppose if A has seen B and C.
now we want to show more users to A. Then B and C should be excluded from that list.
What I'm doing is getting data from firebase like [B, C, D, E, F] as B, C is already seen. So removing those we have [D, E, F].

What's the issue:
Actually getting the same data, again and again, makes more reading numbers. It also slows down the getting of data process. Like if we get a list from firebase and all the profiles in that list are already seen then the device again sends a request to firebase and gets more profiles. it does the same for the new list and if these are also seen so it makes another request again. This takes time and users have to wait until there are profiles to swipe.
Can we make something like that? We just save a list of all the seen profiles at any point and make a rule to exclude those profiles from the search result.
We don't need those profiles at one point but we need to access those profiles to show user he has seen these profiles.
Any help will be appreciated.
I got a little similar case but I didn’t understand

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "Children": {
      "$child_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && 
               root.child('Family').child(
                 root.child('User').child(
                   data.child('parentId').val()
                 ).val()
               ).child('members').child(auth.uid).exists()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update:
there are different node:

```
   database
        |
        `- users
        |   |
        |   `- userId
        |   |      |
        |   |       `-name
        |   |       `-id
        |   |       `-address
        |   |       `-..... more details
        |   `- userId
        |   |      |
        |   |       `-name
        |   |       `-id
        |   |       `-address
        |   |       `-..... more details
        |   |
        |   `- more users . .
        |
        `- swipes
        |  |
        |   `- uniqueId
        |  |        |
        |  |         `- whoSwiped: id
        |  |         `- whoIsSwiped: id
        |  |         `- swipedType: like/dislike
        |  |         `- createdAt: date
        |   `- uniqueId
        |           |
        |            `- whoSwiped: id
        |            `- whoIsSwiped: id
        |            `- swipedType: like/dislike
        |            `- createdAt: date
```

first swiped id is fetched then user from "users" node is fetched ids that are already swiped are removed from the users' list.

Comment: See [Firebase rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters), they are to protect your data, not filter it. Also, we don't know your structure.

Comment: @Jay yes you’re right. Rules are to protect data but I want to find a way to filter data. Is there any possible way to filter data on the server-side instead of the client side? It really makes the app too slow. As it first finds the users that are already seen. After that, It fetches users' data from firebase and then performs a filter on the client-side. As the seen users are increasing the app becomes slower.

Comment: Firestore does a lot of things really well but one thing is doesn't do well is query for data that doesn't exist (it can only query for existing data). I believe what you're asking is how to query for users this user has *not* seen and return those results. One option is to keep a list of users this user has not seen, and then remove them as they are seen. `/users/uid_0/user_ids_not_seen/ list of uids` as new users sign up they are added to that list. It sounds cumbersome but it does scale and the list can be kept smaller by only adding users that match certain criteria like within 50 miles.